# Elixir/Phoenix changing session key

Tags: session, phoenix-framework, elixir

I have sessions, that are generated when user logs in:

```
defp sign_in(user, password, conn) do
   if password == user.password do
     conn
     |> put_session(:current_user, %{id: user.id, username: user.username, role_id: user.role_id, language: 1})
     |> put_flash(:info, "Signed in successfully!")
     |> redirect(to: page_path(conn, :tableshow))
   else
   failed_login(conn)
   end
end
```

and a key "language" that on default assigned to 1 when logged in. However, in the header of the layout/app.html.eex I'm trying to make a button to change the value of the key "language" to 2. How can I change the value of the key? I've read the Plug.Conn, but still not sure:(  Basically, I want to have language switch, so if session "language" key is 1, it will be english, if 2, chinese.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the session variable `:current_user` is just a map, you need to update the map as required using syntax

```
update_map = %{current_map | :key_to_update => value}
```

When the button is clicked on simply perform this in the controller action.

```
conn = put_session(conn, :current_user, 
%{get_session(conn, :current_user) | language: lang_value})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. However I have one issue, I need this button to be in header on all the pages, and put it in layout/app.html.eex, so which controller should I use? I understand how to manipulate the value with controller, but as I need it in app.html.eex, I'm not sure which controller to use. Can you suggest please?

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new controller called `session controller`, and place your controller action there, you may name your controller action `change_language`